# Broadcast a popup message to all online users Java,Jsp

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

i wish to add a functionality to my website that is  to send a pop up message which i've typed, to all online users .  i am able to get user id's of all online users. how could i send message in a jquery pop up to all users. Any one please give me an idea..

Comment: I would suggest to use push service (FCM for example) as Async Jquery call will cause you performance drop. More over you will have more control over messages sent through push

Comment: i  stored the messages in the database and created ajax function in the sidebar file which is include in all jsp pages  to check for new messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this requires 3 components:

**First** you need to make sure that whatever is typed is sent to the server. The easiest way is just via an Ajax call whenever you're done typing (or hit a button)

**Secondly**, you'll have to store the message(s) on the server including what users you've already distributed the message to. This can be just in memory on the server or in a database or file.

**Lastly**, each of the participating users will have to have a mechanism for retrieving the messages. The easiest way is just to have an Ajax call every 10 seconds for instance which asks the server if there are new messages. If there are they are returned and displayed in a popup.

The server can then mark the message as being sent to that user as well as keep a list of users that are active.

**Note** both the Ajax communications could be replaced with websocket connections if you want ultimate performance, but they are somewhat harder to set up, so I'd only recommend that if you have many users or many messages.

Comment: Great Explanation ...  i am planning to store the messages in the database and create and ajax function to check for new  messages. is that alright?

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write an asynchronous script, that runs in the background, requesting from an API, and if it gets some valid response from API, you can popover a message via jQuery!

Comment: Thank you for you consideration